# Gurobi & C#: Index out of range

Tags: c#, gurobi

I am trying to write a decision variable from my MIP model into the console. I am getting the error

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

How can I fix this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Gurobi;    

if (status == GRB.Status.OPTIMAL)
{
   List<List<List<int>>> X_ijk_list = new List<List<List<int>>>();

   Console.WriteLine("X_ijk:");
   for (int k = 0; k < n_machines; ++k)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Maschine" + k);
      X_ijk_list.Add(new List<List<int>>());

      for (int i = 0; i < n_jobs; ++i)
      {
         X_ijk_list[i].Add(new List<int>());

         for (int j = 0; j < n_tasks_job[i]; ++j)
         {
            X_ijk_list[i][j].Add(Convert.ToInt32(X_ijk[i, j, k].Get(GRB.DoubleAttr.X)));  // error here
            Console.Write(X_ijk_list[i][j][k]);
            Console.Write(";");
          }
         Console.WriteLine();
       }
   }
```

Comment: debug your program, and there you will see what your flaw is. You are trying to get or set something while there is no valid entry

Comment: There's a bunch of stuff on here you don't show. What are the values for things like `n_machines` and `n_jobs`? Please read the help, specifically how to create a [mcve]

Comment: More importantly, what is `X_ijk`?

Comment: Ok, so basically I am trying to model a job shop sheduling problem. I have five different jobs which are consisting of 3 to 17 different tasks (job 1 has 12 tasks, job 2 has 3 tasks, job 3 has 17 tasks and so on). Each of the tasks has to be processed on one of 11 machines.
`X_ijk` is a binary variable. It is 1 if task j from job i is being processed on amchine k. Otherwise it's 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing your loop variables. Outer loop is `k`, then `i` then `j`, so

```
X_ijk_list[i][j].Add(Convert.ToInt32(X_ijk[i, j, k].Get(GRB.DoubleAttr.X)));  // error here
```

should be

```
X_ijk_list[k][i].Add(Convert.ToInt32(X_ijk[i, j, k].Get(GRB.DoubleAttr.X)));  // error here
```

and same for the

```
X_ijk_list[k].Add(new List<int>());
```

A *reproducible* code with hardcoded `n_*` variables and dummy `42` instead of `X_ijk[i, j, k].Get(GRB.DoubleAttr.X)`:

```
void Main()
{
    var n_machines = 5;
    var n_jobs = 5;
    var n_tasks_job = new int[] { 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };

    List<List<List<int>>> X_ijk_list = new List<List<List<int>>>();

    Console.WriteLine("X_ijk:");
    for (int k = 0; k < n_machines; ++k)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Maschine" + k);
        X_ijk_list.Add(new List<List<int>>());

        for (int i = 0; i < n_jobs; ++i)
        {
            X_ijk_list[k].Add(new List<int>());

            for (int j = 0; j < n_tasks_job[i]; ++j)
            {
                //X_ijk_list[i][j].Add(Convert.ToInt32(X_ijk[i, j, k].Get(GRB.DoubleAttr.X)));  // error here

                X_ijk_list[k][i].Add(42); // dummy data

                Console.Write(X_ijk_list[k][i][j]);
                Console.Write(";");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

produces

```
X_ijk:
Maschine0
42;42;42;42;42;
42;42;42;42;42;
42;42;42;42;42;
42;42;42;42;42;
42;42;42;42;42;
Maschine1
42;42;42;42;42;
42;42;42;42;42;
42;42;42;42;42;
42;42;42;42;42;
42;42;42;42;42;
Maschine2
42;42;42;42;42;
42;42;42;42;42;
42;42;42;42;42;
42;42;42;42;42;
42;42;42;42;42;
Maschine3
42;42;42;42;42;
42;42;42;42;42;
42;42;42;42;42;
42;42;42;42;42;
42;42;42;42;42;
Maschine4
42;42;42;42;42;
42;42;42;42;42;
42;42;42;42;42;
42;42;42;42;42;
42;42;42;42;42;
```